# WSL Bash Permission denied to create files and directories

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, file-permissions

I've set up `WSL` (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on my Windows 10 to utilize Bash. I've created a Linux user, installed the latest updates and upgrades, and I know how to access the Windows files through `/mnt/c/Users` etc. When I try to create a new file on my desktop, it denies permission:

```
rupert@DESKTOP-GT4APR9:/mnt/c/Users/zolta/OneDrive/Desktop$ touch
file.txt touch: cannot touch 'file.txt': Permission denied
```

How can I grant my Linux Bash user permission to create and modify files and directories on my Windows user desktop? Is that possible at all?

Comment: Please specifiy your windows build version (terminal winver): touch /mnt/c/Users/me/Downloads/test.txt works for me, winver 1709. WSL is changing quite quickly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes

Comment: It's V 1803 (build 17134.753)

Comment: Questions about interacting with software as an end-user, as opposed to *developing* software, generally belong on our sister site [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) (or [unix.se] for questions about UNIX tools specifically -- though this is a bit marginal there, being principally about filesystem user mapping between Windows and WSL accounts), not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That said, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/ is very relevant; if you wanted to just *bypass* permissions and let the WSL instance access anything it wanted on the Windows side, the mount options section will show you how to do that.

Comment: Had the same issue. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1323645/unable-to-change-file-permissions-on-ubuntu-bash-for-windows-10/1343737#1343737?newreg=29702ddd3e8341469a84603d63b6bcd3) worked for me.

Comment: If this is an "one-time-thing" you can run WSL process as elevated process (run as administrator)

Answer (score 1):

I would use sudo, i.e. `sudo touch file.txt`. Works for me in WSL2 Ubuntu (which is Debian based)

Answer (score 1):

The path with which you are having problems,

```
rupert@DESKTOP-GT4APR9:/mnt/c/Users/zolta/OneDrive/Desktop
```

appears to live on OneDrive: While I am not a OneDrive expert, my understanding is that to access it from the command line, the remote data stored on OneDrive has to synced locally.

If you `cd rupert@DESKTOP-GT4APR9:/mnt/c/Users/zolta`, can you `touch file.txt` there?

What about accessing these folders from `cmd` or `pwsh`?

Answer (score 1):

By default, on a brand new Windows 10 install, the user sub-directories (Desktop, Documents, etc...) are located within the OneDrive directory, inside the home directory (that is troublesome in my opinion). 
It will allow synchronisation between devices.

I do not know if WSL is able to access such a directory, like it cannot access USB storage for exemple.

You may want to ls first in order to see if you can access:
`ls -alh /mnt/c/Users/zolta/OneDrive/Desktop`

If you can see your files, that is a write access issue. You might correct it by changing the owner or the directory and it's content:
`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/c/Users/zolta/OneDrive/Desktop`

If you cannot, try using sudo:
`sudo ls -alh /mnt/c/Users/zolta/OneDrive/Desktop`

If nothing can be seen, or an error raise, that probably means WSL cannot access this directory.
In that case, I suggest you change default directory as stated in the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/configuration-of-the-my-documents-folder-dfd9a90d-8f80-18d6-e7cc-f1566fc3b10b).